# Is it possible to automatically insert a column value in a table based on column values in another table?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL database for a rental business, which will receive data from a webpage using PHP.

One table contains customer information and for the purposes of my problem, the relevant columns are **customers.id** (the primary key), **customers.name** (self-explanatory), and **customers.active** of datatype Boolean (to indicate whether or not they are currently renting). As one customer may have multiple non-simultaneous rental contracts, there can be multiple ids associated with a single customer but only one can be active.

The other table contains records of individual payment transactions and has two columns relevant to this problem: **payments.customer_name** and **payments.customer_id** (a foreign key referencing customers.id).

Certain users will be permitted to insert data into the payments table via a webpage using PHP. For greater ease of use, upon entering a value for payments.customer_name I would like the correct id to be automatically inserted into **payments.customer_id**.

I know it would be possible to first enter just customer_name, use mysqli_query to select the record for that name where customers.active = 1 and then get the correct value for customer_id from the result object but I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this using only MySQL. I know generated columns cannot reference another table but maybe there's another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `id` of a customer from its `name` with the following `select` query:

```
select id
from customers 
where name = :customer_name and active = 1
```

Beware that, if there are duplicate `name`s, this potentially returns more than one row. You should really have a `unique` constraint on `name` for this approach to be safe.

You can use that in an `insert`:

```
insert into payment (customer_id, other_column1, other_column2, ...)
select c.id, :other_column1, :other_column2, ...
from customers c
where c.name = :customer_name and c.active = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware that SELECT could be used within an INSERT INTO statement. Did exactly what I needed it to do.